# How to get path of servlet to include in .jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to call a servlet in a `jsp` file by using the following tag to read some data sent by the servlet.

```
<jsp:include page="../View_Accountant.java" flush = "true" />
```

It's not working, I think the URL of servlet is wrong.

My project directory.

[image: project directory image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsp include page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html) need to get as parameter a JSP file (or other file) and not the Servlet class file

> The jsp:include element is processed when a JSP page is executed

Comment: If I should pass url of .class file of servlet.. what should be the url of View_Accountant.class..how do i get it?

Comment: Edit: If I should pass url of .jsp file of servlet.. what should be the url of View_Accountant file ..how do i get it?

Comment: @chandu usually you define entry point for servlet in web.xml or in annotation and then call the endpoint as `/servlet/viewaccount` with ajax call or form submission or browser GET request

Answer (score 0):

All the Project Servlet's names are stored in the **web.xml** file. Just take the servlet **URL** from there and use it instead of **View_Accountant.java**

Comment: attach a screenshot of your web.xml

Comment: <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
these tags..

Comment: Is there any tag like this?:

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/firstservlet1.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: I am using annotations instead url mapping.

Comment: ok then, anything like this?

@WebServlet("/driverapprove.do") in your servlet?

Comment: of course..I have them since I use annotations. but what is .do extension?

Comment: ok, so instead of `View_Accountant.java` use the value in annotation
this value is used to refer wherever you want to use the servlet.

Also one thing to be noted is that, JSP is used at client side and servlet is used at server side, so it's a bit tricky to get the request instantly